# Model Binding from a Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to bind json to my model in ASP .net MVC 4. The model does get created but the properties are not filled.

My javascript:

```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
        url: "/Admin/" + method,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray()),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success == true) {


            }
        }
    });
```

My Class:

```
public class Taxes {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; } }
```

My Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddTax(Taxes tax)
{

    return Json(new { Success = true, tax.Id });
}
```

The Json:

```
[{"name":"Id","value":"1"},{"name":"Name","value":"fsdfs"},{"name":"Rate","value":"18"}]
```

The result is:

```
Id = 0
Name = Null
Rate = 0
```

Comment: Can u explain what you have tried already ?

Comment: try this json, it shall fill your model [{"Id":"1","Rate":"18", "Name":"fsdfs"}].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you've written what your problem is, but you're just not reading it. Your call to
**JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray())** is generating this for you:

```
[{"name":"Id","value":"1"},{"name":"Name","value":"fsdfs"},{"name":"Rate","value":"18"}]
```

Which can only be mapped to something like this:

```
IEnumerable<SampleClass> model
```

Where SampleClass has properties:

```
public class SampleClass
    {
         public string name {get;set;}
         public string value {get;set;}
    }
```

You need different kind of method, one which will:

1. Create javascript object for you
2. For each member of array created with form.serializeArray(), it will
   add property to object with name member.name and with value
   member.value

JSON.stringify will then generate proper JSON representation of your Taxes class.

Check the implementation here:

https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject